# python sklearn not found, although installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, conda

I installed `scikit-learn` as well as `numpy` and `scipy` with `conda` for python 3.6. But I am not able to import `sklearn` in python3.6. What is wrong and how can I fix it?
Here is what I see in `conda list`:

```
numpy                     1.12.1                   py36_0 
scipy                     0.19.0              np112py36_0 
scikit-learn              0.19.0              np112py36_0
```

And here is the error message I got trying to import `sklearn`:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I'm using OS X and conda 4.3.24.

Comment: Are you using the right environment ? Conda list lists the packages in the default environment

Comment: `conda list -n myenv` where myenv is the name of your virtual environment

Comment: `conda info --envs` to list your environments.  The one with the `*` symbol is the environment you currently have activated.

Comment: Where are you entring this: import sklearn?

Comment: Your Python repl doesn't look like it came from an anaconda distribution.